# how to browse a page on port 8080 from a virtualbox machine?

Tags: apache, virtualbox, nat

We have a small LAN.
On one of the machines Apache is running under win8 and listening on port 8080. I can't edit this machine. Hence to browse it I use something like 192.168.2.4:8080/index.php
My machine is a Mac and I need to test a site under IE8, so I have a virtualbox running XP.
I can browse any internet site from it but I can't access the Apache server. I can do it from my Mac but not from its virtualbox.
I tried everything I could, changed the network adapter in VB's settings to NAT, network with NAT, bridge etc, no results.

Any idea about how to solve this problem? We're not sysadmins and we've already lost a working day on this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

if changing network adapters doesn't help and you have access to router control panel, i have an idea but it's little lame.

- add a portforward rule on router for port `8080`
- get ip address [here](http://www.myipaddress.com/show-my-ip-address/) of your router and access it with port `8080`, you'll get forwarded to your apache server

NOTE: if you lan is under more lan's, you'll have to repeat first point for every router, so you can try only if nothing else is working